# I want to use Google sign-in in ios, but the method is different. How should I do it?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-signin

[image]

I want to use Google login. However, the handle method is different. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)